# How I can use strpos in search by foreach in array

Tags: php

The problem lies in the fact that I have to type the full name for the search phrase.
Maybe can I use strpos in this?

```
    if ($filter && $searchOption && $searchPhrase && $sortField == "createDate" && $order == "asc") {
        usort($caseList, function ($a, $b) {
            /* @var $a CMCase */
            /* @var $b CMCase */
            $time1 = strtotime($a->createDate);
            $time2 = strtotime($b->createDate);
            return $time1 > $time2;
        });

        }  else if ($filter && $searchOption == "search_customer" && $searchPhrase && $sortField && $order) {

        $list = $caseList;
        $caseList = array();
        foreach ($list as $case) {
            if ($case->customerName == $searchPhrase) {
                $caseList[] = $case;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is input and what is expected ? give some data.

Comment: Please explain further what you want to do.

Comment: Please, provide sample input and output that you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution:

```
// Searching
    {
        if ($filter && $searchOption == "search_customer" && $searchPhrase && $sortField && $order) {

            $list = array();
            foreach ($caseList as $case) {
                if (stripos($case->customerName,$searchPhrase)!== FALSE)  {
                    $list[] = $case;
                }
            }
            $caseList = $list;

        } else if ($filter && $searchOption == "search_request" && $searchPhrase && $sortField && $order) {

            $list = array();
            foreach ($caseList as $case) {
                if (stripos($case->identifier,$searchPhrase)!== FALSE) {
                    $list[] = $case;
                }
            }
            $caseList = $list;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your code like this:

```
$result = array_filter($caseList, function($case) use ($searchPhrase){
   return stripos($case->customerName, $searchPhrase) !== FALSE;
})
```

But you still need to be more concrete. 
! I used stripos to case insensitive search. See the [manual](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.stripos.php)

P.S. Just try this instead of your code:

```
if ($searchOption == "search_customer" && $searchPhrase)  use ($searchPhrase) {
     $list = array_filter($caseList,function($case) {
        return stripos($case->customerName, $searchPhrase) !== false;
     });
}
```

Comment: Try again with edited code. I just misled arquments.

Comment: Thank you for help but this don't work. In return $searchPhrase is not defined and where is "use" i have this problem "use not allowed inside a function" :(

Comment: show me your code pls. It'll be good if you give me a link to pastebin or similar. I'll change it.

Comment: Well, you rewrite it and for now I don't know what you need at all. My solution copes well with your primary task. 

And my solution deal with your example with "Toms".
I dunno, what data you have, but can show you code for your example with "Tom"